# Pointer or Duplicate?

Tags: android, performance, ram

I have util class which has a static arraylist filled with custom object model.

And in another class (basic custom array adapter), i access that data and create a reference for me.

Like;
mEmojiList = EmojiUtil.getRecent():

Question is;
"Did i duplicate recent arraylist?"

P.S:
Please dont tell me "why dont you just use static access way?"
-This adapter is inner class of a fragment that uses in viewpager and loads another datas up to fragments position.

Thanks

Comment: what does *Did i duplicate recent arraylist?* mean ?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of `getRecent()`. If it just returns a reference to the list without copying it, there's no duplication.